# Android Query SQLite strange error

Tags: android, sqlite, select

this query gives me error `"no such column: ANTIPASTI"` I do not understand why the `WHERE` clause gives this error:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, prodotto, reparto FROM Prodotti WHERE reparto=ANTIPASTI";
```

LOG CAT:

> 02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.ristor/com.example.ristor.Interno_tavolo}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ANTIPASTI
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, prodotto, reparto FROM
>   Prodotti WHERE reparto=ANTIPASTI 02-14 13:28:39.376:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-14 13:28:39.376:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 02-14 13:28:39.376:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-14 13:28:39.376:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1987): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ANTIPASTI
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, prodotto, reparto FROM
>   Prodotti WHERE reparto=ANTIPASTI 02-14 13:28:39.376:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) 02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   com.example.ristor.Interno_tavolo.listaProdotti(Interno_tavolo.java:55)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   com.example.ristor.Interno_tavolo.onCreate(Interno_tavolo.java:46)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 02-14
>   13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>   02-14 13:28:39.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1987):   ... 11 more

Comment: use `'ANTIPASTI'`. since the column is a `String` you should compare to a `String`.

Comment: Are you sure you have the "ANTIPASTI" column in the "Prodotti" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ANTIPASTI` is a literal string, you need to enclose it in `'` single quotes like below.

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, prodotto, reparto FROM Prodotti WHERE reparto = 'ANTIPASTI' ";
```